# How to get the FindData structure from the IShellItem2.GetProperty output in Delphi code?

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl, delphi-xe5

I'm enumerating the Windows shell with IShellFolder and struggle with getting the FindData structure from the TPropVariant output of IShellItem2.GetProperty so that I can explore its content.

The question is: How do I get FindData from the TPropVariant output in Delphi code? C++ snippets don't help me in this case (that's why I'm posting, because there are several around that I haven't been able translate correctly.)

What I have is:

```
var  
  ShellItem2: IShellItem2;
  ppropvar: TPropVariant;
  HR: HResult;
  FindData: TWin32FindData;
  FileSize: Int64;

if ShellItem2.GetProperty(PKEY_FindData, ppropvar) = S_OK then
begin
  //It's ok, then how do I get FindData?

  //Calculate the file size, for instace.
  FileSize := FindData.nFileSizeLow or Int64(FindData.nFileSizeHigh) shl 32;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any formal documentation about how a `WIN32_FIND_DATA` is stored in a `PROPVARIANT`. However, based on a code snippet found in [this Qt code patch](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/31301/qtbug29447_diag.patch), the last field of the `PROPVARIANT` holds a pointer to a `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`, so try something like this:

```pascal
type
  PWin32FindDataW = ^TWin32FindDataW;
  PPWin32FindDataW = ^PWin32FindDataW;
var
  ShellItem2: IShellItem2;
  ppropvar: TPropVariant;
  FindData: PWin32FindDataW;
  FileSize: UInt64;
begin
  ...
  if ShellItem2.GetProperty(PKEY_FindData, ppropvar) = S_OK then begin
    FindData := PPWin32FindDataW(PByte(@ppropvar) + sizeof(ppropvar) - sizeof(Pointer))^;
    // alternatively:
    // FindData := PWin32FindDataW(ppropvar.caub.pElems);
    if FindData <> nil then begin
      FileSize := FindData.nFileSizeLow or (UInt64(FindData.nFileSizeHigh) shl 32);
      ...
    end;
    PropVariantClear(ppropvar);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: The alternative FindData is always nil, but the first one works. Only on some items it is nil, which is what I suspected it would be. So it's necessary to check FindData for nil. Unfortunately this means I can't use it for my purpose (getting file sizes as data and not string from a USB connected Android phone), but a big thanks to you!

Comment: The code has memory outflow. Don`t forget about PropVariantClear.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I see no memory overflow in this code. Please elaborate.

Comment: After call of ShellItem2.GetProperty ppropvar.vt will have value of VT_UI1 or VT_VECTOR, so ShellItem2.GetProperty allocates a buffer for TWin32FindDataW record. And this buffer should be freed with PropVariantClear.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov That would be a memory leak, not a memory overflow.

Comment: Yes, sure, my bad. Leak instead of overflow.

Comment: @user12523890 I see why my "alternative" did not work.  I have corrected it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The alternative is now working as well as the first FindData assignment. My statement that the alternative FindData was always nil was also wrong. When it wasn't there was an access violation on the FileSize calculation instead,

Comment: @ZHN the only way to get an AV on the `FileSize` calculation is if the `FindData` pointer is invalid. That should be fixed now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, exactly. I haven't had any problems with it now.

Comment: FWIW, the type of PROPVARIANT for a byte array ("buffer" as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-finddata) should be VT_VECTOR | VT_UI1 or VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1. It should be tested, not assumed before using pointers. But there's an easy way to manipulate all PROPVARIANTs: PropVariantXXX functions from propsys.dll. ex: PropVariantToBuffer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propvarutil/nf-propvarutil-propvarianttobuffer

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetItemFindData(AItem: IShellItem2; out AFindData: TWin32FindDataW): Boolean;
var
  PV: TPropVariant;
begin
  Result := False;
  PV.vt := VT_EMPTY;
  if AItem.GetProperty(PKEY_FindData, PV) = S_OK then
    begin
      if (PV.vt = VT_UI1 or VT_VECTOR) and (PV.caub.cElems = SizeOf(AFindData)) and Assigned(PV.caub.pElems) then
        begin
          CopyMemory(@AFindData, PV.caub.pElems, SizeOf(AFindData));
          Result := True;
        end;
      PropVariantClear(PV);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: This alternative also works as expected. Thanks for educating us.